# DNN / ASP.NET - how to extract number from a textfield?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to build a form with DNN and ASP.NET, and am having trouble extracting a number from a textbox meant to contain a decimal number.

The rest of the form works just fine (the other fields are strings), it correctly submits said fields to the database.

The form in my ascx file has:

```
<div class="dnnFormItem">
            <div class="dnnLabel">
                <asp:Label ID="myDecimalLabel" runat="server" Text="Enter decimal here:"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="myDecimalTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>            
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" controltovalidate="myDecimalTextBox" validationexpression="^\d*\.?\d*$" errormessage="Invalid input" />
</div>
```

And in the Add/Update method of my ascx.cs file, I have:

```
MyDecimalValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(myDecimalTextBox.Text.Trim()) ? 0 : Decimal.Parse(myDecimalTextBox.Text.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Yet the conversion always produces a result of 0, even when another number is entered.

I have checked that it didn't mistakenly consider the textbox to be empty (it doesn't), so the failure is in the conversion. I have also tried TryParse and Convert.ToDecimal, to no avail. In fact, I have also tried this with Double or Int, and that didn't work either, I just can't seem to be able to extract a number from that textbox. I have also tried making the TextBox the number type, and that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for giggles, comment out the line with the assignment and just put MyDecimalValue = Decimal.Parse("10") and see if everything works as you expect?

Comment: I just tried, it correctly submits 10 to the database

Comment: What happens if you omit the check and use just the decimal.parse without the invariant like MyDecimalValue = Decimal.Parse(myDecimalTextBox.Text.Trim())? might be some weird framework issue with terniary and parsing. I'd start debugging it by taking it apart and trying just one piece at a time.